# How to compare two tables from CSV files?

Tags: python, csv

I need to take a column from one csv file and compare this column with another column from another csv file to find a match.

I can not use Panda, I extract tables and stuck after..

```
def first():
    with open('1.csv') as csv_file:
        for line in csv_file.readlines():
            array = line.split(',')
            list_pk = array[1]

def sec():
    with open('2.csv') as csv_file:
        for line in csv_file.readlines():
            array = line.split(',')
            list_fk = array[0]
```

Comment: Should the whole row match or only specific columns? Also, how big are your files? can they be loaded in memory?

Comment: @urban specific column, the file is small max 4000 rows

Comment: Did you read the [documentatin for the `csv` module?](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). Anyway, I find that instead of writing python scripts it's usually easier to use the `csvkit` to `csvjoin` the files together and `csvgrep` values, although sometimes these tools are limited

Comment: Define what you mean by "compare" _in your question_. You're also not opening the csv files proper — suggest you look at the examples in the documentation.

Comment: I guess you should be storing the first item of each line in some data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it will help you

```
def findMatch():
  with open('old.csv', 'r',  newline='') as t1, open('new.csv', 'r',  newline='') as t2:
    for line1,line2 in zip(t1,t2):
      if line1.split(' ')[colum_index]!=line2.split(' ')[colum_index]:
        print(line1,line2)
findMatch()
```

- for more help please refer [csv doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)
- for zip/izip refer    [zip/izip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel)

using zip_longest

```
from itertools import zip_longest
def findMatch():
  with open('old.csv', 'r',  newline='') as t1, open('new.csv', 'r',  newline='') as t2:
    for line in zip_longest(t1,t2):
      print(line)
      if line[0]!=line[1]:
        print("nq")
findMatch()
```

zip_longest reference:-[zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)

Comment: When you `open()` csv files in Python 3.x, you should use `newline=''` as shown in the documentation.

Comment: @soheshdoshi `if line1.split(' ')[1] != line2.split(' ')[0]: IndexError: list index out of range` seems like I'm getting this exception because of the column length are different

Comment: @Nikolai tha's why i give you zip/izip reference.please do some research